# PHP strange header

Tags: php

Working for a friend to move her website to a new server, her developer wrote the following code as main index.php:

```
<?php
header("Location: /s/subdir/r/index/");
?>
```

On the new server it's not working.  I would understand if it was `header("Location: /subdir/index.php");`. What purpose do the `/s` and `/r` serve? This is an old website.

Answer (score 2):

This header will redirect user's browser from http://example.com/ to http://example.com/s/subdir/r/index/.

Probably `/s`, `/r` are directories/subdirectories on the old server.

Comment: The /s and /r are not sub-directories.  That's what's strange.  It's like some arcane coding style.

Comment: As Ivan mentioned below, it can be a query for PHP engine. I.e. the engine looks for '/r' or '/s' in URL and does some logic based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it depends on the server's settings (routing) or application's settings (php engine routing).

So this header will redirect your page to "/s/subdir/r/index/" it can be a real directory OR it can be query for exact php engine.

For example Yii2 has this system for routing pages: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: I believe you are correct Ivan.  It seems to be telling Apache to open /subdir/index.php.  I'll investigate further.